# Electrical effects of loose wire

Tags: failure

I was remotely helping someone troubleshoot a problem with a 120v house circuit and from the symptoms was pretty sure it was a bad / loose wire in an outlet.

I had them unplug everything while waiting for an electrician. (Person didn't have direct access to breaker.)

I was right, the electrician found a loose wire in the backstab of an outlet.

What are the electrical effects of this in downstream electronics with a marginal connection like this?

What I think I know / understand: a poor connection causes arcing that increases resistance - so there is a fire hazard as well as a voltage drop.

Is there also a surging effect?  If so, how?  Could this destroy, say, a computer?  What would be the mechanism?   Would a surge protector help you or are they only activated above 120v?

(And yes, everyone should install AFCI for this reason.)

I was thinking this belonged on the diy stack, but I am looking for more of an EE explanation... Let me know if this is more appropriate for diy.

Edit:  Can we not get distracted by the lack of "direct access" to the breaker?  It's not relevant to the question and I don't want to explain the exact living circumstances.  Also, this isn't my building. The facility staff was already notified, hence the electrician who was scheduled to come.  I'm interested in the side effects of arcing within electrical circuits on devices downstream, not code compliance.

Comment: Possible outcomes would depend on what else is on the circuit. If you had a motor or other inductive load, that might generate higher voltage ‘spikes’ and that might kill a computer over time - or just about any other but of consumer gear as most devices have a switched mode power supply. The way to be sure would be to get a power analyser that can log the data over time. What it tells you might be surprising.

Comment: Isn't it required by code in most jurisdictions to have direct access to the breaker?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there also a surging effect? If so, how? Could this destroy, say, a computer? What would be the mechanism? Would a surge protector help you or are they only activated above 120v?

First, arcing isn't that big a deal with failing backstabs, because UL has spent a lot of bandwidth making sure they fail dead instead of fail deadly.  So failure and shutdown is the norm for backstabs.

However,  arcing and interruptions do upset inductive loads.  Just like capacitors resist changes in voltage (and expend their stored energy flowing theoretically infinite current trying to hold voltage), inductors resist changes in current, and will expend their stored energy creating theoretically infinite voltage trying to hold current.  This any abrupt interruption of power tends to lead to a voltage spike as inductors react to it.

> (And yes, everyone should install AFCI for this reason.)

Or, just don't use backstabs lol.

AFCIs were originally specced in rooms where electric blankets would be used, or where cords were frequently (and vigorously) crushed by furniture.  That is to say, bedrooms. (guess they had some "real Casanovas" on the NEC committee).  However, field reports showed their #1 reason for tripping was backstabs!

Comment: Agreed on the backstabs, but everyone is getting distracted by the "no direct access to the breakers."  It's not my building and its not relevant to the question.  I didn't want to go into the details of the living arrangement.

Comment: @rrauenza alright, removed.

Comment: Thanks..  And I wish they would outlaw backstabs.  I personally always buy the "heavy duty" or "commercial" quality.